# Want to get data from other website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to get data from other website using NuGet but its not get anything.
var aTags showing null value.

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = getHtmlWeb.Load("https://www.google.com");
        var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
        int counter = 1;
        if (aTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var aTag in aTags)
            {
                Label1.Text += counter + ". " + aTag.InnerHtml + " - " + aTag.Attributes["href"].Value + "\t" + "<br />";
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Am i doing anything wrong that no one answering my question?

Comment: Your code is nothing to do with nuget; you just installed a package from nuget. Look like you are screen-scraping instead of getting data. Please google how to screen-scrape.